# Time Picker Dialog crash on Samsung S4 OS 4.3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-timepicker

I keep on getting this issue whenever I click on Timepicker. This issue is not occurring on any other devices, Following is the error log:

```
Error log:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.TimePicker.updateInputState(TimePicker.java:846)
    at android.widget.TimePicker.onSaveInstanceState(TimePicker.java:561)
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:13117)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2828)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2828)
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:13100)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1930)
    at android.app.Dialog.onSaveInstanceState(Dialog.java:407)
    at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onSaveInstanceState(TimePickerDialog.java:216)
    at android.app.Activity.saveManagedDialogs(Activity.java:1269)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1187)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1240)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There is similar issue: [Force Close on Changing time: Time Picker (NPE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150655/force-close-on-changing-time-time-picker-npe), with a link to [android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24387), with one suggestion how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this where you want to Trigger TimePicker::>

```
int hour,minute;
TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, 
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
hour = selectedHour;
    minute = selectedMinute;
 }


}, hour, minute, false);// Yes 24 hour time
mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
mTimePicker.updateTime(hour, minute);
mTimePicker.show();
```